# How can Jedi learn to use tutaminis without hurting themselves?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, jedi, jedi-training

Tutaminis is a very useful ability because it allows a Jedi to stop blaster bolts and lightsaber attacks. But how can someone learn this without losing a hand? This is how it plays out in my mind:

> "Ok, so now I'm going to stab your hand with my lightsaber. Be sure to remember your training."
>
> "Yes, master, I'm ready."
>
> "Ok."
>
> *hand gets stabbed*

Then the padawan screams because he did it wrong and got his hand chopped off by a lightsaber.

Comment: Getting your hand cut off with a lightsaber isn't that big of a deal in the Star Wars universe

Comment: @Valorum It means you have to wear only one glove.

Comment: You could use Iroh's method and teach the lightning redirection technique's motion and philosophy the without actually shooting lightning at your student, because, as Iroh puts it, *"What? Are you crazy? Lightning is very dangerous! ...I'm not going to shoot lightning at you!"* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5t_4aQ8UM8w

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Well, to be honest, I don't see how someone can learn from philosophy alone, but you have a point.

Comment: They would just use a training lightsaber that simply singes things that it cuts, not a real live lightsaber.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[Blasters have stun settings](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stun), and the Jedi use [training droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Marksman-H_training_remote) and [training lightsabers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Training_lightsaber) which have limited power. Presumably Jedi practice tutaminis with these before attempting to block blaster bolts and lightsabers at full power. It's not all that different than Luke's attempts to use a lightsaber to block low power blaster bolts from the training droid on the *Millennium Falcon* in Episode IV -- he was actually shot by the training droid but wasn't harmed because the training droid wasn't firing bolts at full power.

Answer (score 1):

They would simply attempt to stop the bolt or saber moving past them instead of directly at them until they mastered the technique.

The force allows a user to interact with matter and energy remotely so there is no reason they would need to be in harm’s way for learning the skill.

Comment: It has o be touching. Stoping a blaster bolt would be like Kylo ren did, and not using the ability. Welcome to Stack exchange and thank you for answering.

Comment: @xpert are you sure about that? I can’t find any requirement for contact here: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tutaminis

Comment: There is this scene from star wars the old republic where there is a fight in a forest. The sith disarms the jedi and the jedi blocks the lightsaber without it hurting her. You might be right. I will look at the link in a bit.